# Description syntax of smarty because after some code my variable already overwrite

Tags: content-management-system, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

Can someone explain this code int Smarty file:

```
{hypnosOnepagecheckout nSeitenTyp=$nSeitenTyp return=onepagecheckout}
```

because I try to assign some variable that have name "Zahlungsarten" to smarty file but after that line code the variable alredy overwrite .

For note I develop some payment plugin to jtl shop cms.

Answer (score 0):

This calls a smarty plugin named `hypnosOnepagecheckout` with the parameters `nSeitenTyp` and `return` and their according values after the equal sign.